# CSS-How to organize copies of classes into a single column

Tags: html, css, margin

So I have something like this:

```
                       <div class="modalProd" id="Box1">
                        <span class ="modalProduct">
                            Box1
                        </span>
                        <span class = "modalQuantity">
                            Quantity: 0
                        </span>
                        <span class = "modalPrice">
                            $0
                        </span>
                        <span class="removeModal">
                            -
                        </span>
                        <span class = "addModal" >
                            +
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modalProd" id="Box2">
                        <span class ="modalProduct">
                            Box2
                        </span>
                        <span class = "modalQuantity">
                            Quantity: 0
                        </span>
                        <span class = "modalPrice">
                            $0
                        </span>
                        <span class="removeModal">
                            -
                        </span>
                        <span class = "addModal" >
                            +
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

together with my css it looks like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/hh77xg1t/1/

obviously this is impractical but works fine for now. But then i add another item like this

```
                        <div id="Clothes1">
                        <span class ="modalProduct">
                            Clothes1
                        </span>
                        <span class = "modalQuantity">
                            Quantity: 0
                        </span>
                        <span class = "modalPrice">
                            $0
                        </span>
                        <span class="removeModal">
                            -
                        </span>
                        <span class = "addModal" >
                            +
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

and you can clearly see how it messes up the formatting:

https://jsfiddle.net/hh77xg1t/3/

is there a way i can fix this without entering different margin-left values for every product? In other words, is there something like margin-left except instead of measuring the margin from the closest element, i can specify the margin from the very leftmost edge of the modal?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something with some built in structure such as a table or a list? From what you are explaining it seems like either one of these solutions would accomplish what you are going after.

```
   <div id="Clothes1">
    <table>
    <tr>
     <td class=" ">Clothes1</td>
     <td>Quantity: 0</td>
     <td>$0</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td class=" ">+</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
table, tr, td {
 border: none;
}
```

Comment: perhaps i am doing something wrong but when i try this every element is just stuck together with no spaces in between

Answer (score 0):

It's because there's no particular width for each element, the width of `Box1` and `Box2` is the same because they have same number of letters whereas `Clothes1` has greater width than the other two so the margin of quantity shifts a bit, try this

```
.modalProd {
 width:100%;
}
.modalProd > span{
 width:32%;
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0;
}
.modalProd .addModal{
 width:3%;
}




<div class="modalProd" id="Box1">
   <span class="modalProduct">
       Box1
   </span>
   <span class="modalQuantity">
       Quantity: 0
   </span>
   <span class="modalPrice">
       $0
   </span>
   <span class="removeModal">
       -
   </span>
   <span class="addModal">
       +
   </span>
</div>
<div class="modalProd" id="Box2">
   <span class="modalProduct">
       Box2
   </span>
   <span class="modalQuantity">
       Quantity: 0
   </span>
   <span class="modalPrice">
       $0
   </span>
   <span class="removeModal">
       -
   </span>
   <span class="addModal">
       +
   </span>
</div>
<div class="modalProd" id="Clothes1"> /* add modalProd class here, it wasn't there in your original code */
   <span class="modalProduct">
       Clothes1
   </span>
   <span class="modalQuantity">
       Quantity: 0
   </span>
   <span class="modalPrice">
       $0
   </span>
   <span class="removeModal">
       -
   </span>
   <span class="addModal">
       +
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make all your span elements to have `display:inline-block`. This allows you to specify width, height, margins and padding to the span while keeping them on the same horizontal row.

Also set all the row elements a fluid width of 100%. I have added a width of 2em for the + and - elements and subtracted that from total width using `calc` css function.

Please check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santon/r4ddbk37/)

Answer (score 0):

wrap everything in a `<table></table>`. Then wrap each of your blocks for box1,box2,clothes,ect. into `<tr></tr>` to make table rows. Then wrap each individual entry in your rows in a `<td></td>`. It's a little labor-intensive, but its really the only way to do it right with html. You can hide the table borders in your css with   `table {border: none;}`